# Django Staticfiles used with Reportlab

Tags: django, reportlab

I have a situation where I  have a view that is creating a pdf using reportlab.

I have to register a font file and I can do so with the following code:

```
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Arial', settings.STATIC_ROOT + '/fonts/Arial.ttf'))
```

my static_root is set to :

```
STATIC_ROOT = str(ROOT_DIR('staticfiles'))
```

This will work but it means I have to run ./manage.py collectstatic in development in order for the static file which I understand as incorrect practice but I notice you doing it.

As this is an edge case where Im not calling a static file through a url I should just copy the font file manually into the STATIC_ROOT in dev and not run collectstatic.

Or should I try grab the file via the static_url?

This static file business really bakes my noodle :(

Comment: Why would running collectstatic in development be incorrect practice? Development environment should be in my opinion as close as possible to production environment, otherwise one might face all sorts of issues when deploying. This is one of the principles of continuous delivery.

Comment: Thanks borut. I agree. Im asking as the django documentation seems to talk about collecstatic in relation to production only and was wondering how other django devs do it or more importantly what is good practice?

Comment: I think it's a good practice to setup your development environment in the same manner as production, with logging and all. But that's just my opinion. I hardly ever run Django development server.